# Drools Engine: Memory management for a high-traffic application

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

The purpose of this code is to monitor the flow of events of different categories, and raise different levels of alarms in different categories, based on the frequency of events of the corresponding category.
The level of alarms for each category increases progressively, and only 1 **Alarm** object is inserted per level per category. **Alarm**s must expire if they are old enough AND can no longer satisfy any rule. The time for each level of alarm to expire for each category is different. Also **Event**s must expire at different times to achieve the optimum memory usage.

The automatic event life-cycle management does not work at all when declaring both **Alarm** and **Event** objects as *event*s. If I declare **Alarm** as *fact*, objects of type **Event** get discarded as intended, but unsurprisingly, objects of type **Alarm** remain in the memory forever.

Question: How can I manage the memory properly and discard the unnecessary **Alarm**/**Event** objects? Utilizing Drools' inferred expiration is preferred; can I change my code in any way to make it work?(Like adding time constraints to the existing rules, maybe?) Adding an *expires* tag to the **Event**/**Alarm** types is a last resort.

Thanks in advance

```
declare Event
    @role(event)
end

declare Alarm
    @role(event)
end

rule "Alarm Level 1"
    when
        $e : Event()
        not (Alarm(category == $e.getCategory(), level == 1)
    then
        Alarm a = new Alarm($e.getCategory());
        a.setLevel(1);
        insert(a);
end


rule "Alarm Level 2"
    when
        $alarm : Alarm(level == 1)
        not (Alarm(category == $alarm.getCategory(), level == 2)
        Number( intValue >= 5 ) from accumulate(
            $e : Event(category == $alarm.getCategory()) over window:time( 1h ),
            count($e) )
    then
        Alarm a = new Alarm($alarm.getCategory());
        a.setLevel(2);
        insert(a);
end

rule "Alarm Level 3"
    when
        $alarm : Alarm(level == 2)
        not (Alarm(category == $alarm.getCategory(), level == 3)
        Number( intValue >= 15 ) from accumulate(
            $e : Event(category == $alarm.getCategory()) over window:time( 2h ),
            count($e) )
    then
        Alarm a = new Alarm($alarm.getCategory());
        a.setLevel(3);
        insert(a);
end
```

EDIT: 
The project's requirements are to monitor the frequency of **Event**s and fire **Alarm**s if necessary(described in more details above). Those **Alarm**s can also participate in firing of a set of rules, each with their own time limit.

In other words, I need to write a rule like this:

```
rule "A"
    when
        $a Alarm($param : some_param, some_constraints, happened_in_last_n_secs)
        $e Event(some_param == $param, some_constraints, happened_in_last_m_secs)
    then
        do_stuff
end
```

Is there something like the code below in Drools?

```
$eventA : Event( this before[ 0s, 4m ] time.now )
```

Comment: I guess you haven't written down all requirements in your question. But I'm sure that, given all requirements, it is possible to write rules that take care of retracting Event and Alarm facts from Working Memory. An explicit `@expires` should not be necessary.

Comment: I edited the question. Hope It clarifies my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Now` fact automatically provided by Drools.

Consider creating this event and updating its time stamp whenever a rule driven by a timer with appropriate interval fires.

**Edit**
The automatic time-stamping by Drools must be considered as a sloppy solution. It is most certainly suitable for applications where the true time stamp isn't paramount or not available. Otherwise, an event's time stamp should be determined where the event is created and become one of the event's properties. You can access this field like any other attribute and compare its value using temporal operators.

Comment: Is this possible while running the engine in _Stream mode_? How can I access the _timestamp_ field? So if I understood correctly, I should: 1: Insert a fact and write a corresponding rule for it to update its timestamp. 2: Use `this before` to compare my events' time with this fact

Comment: Considering Drools has a time window functionality, isn't there an easy way to get a reference to the latest Alarm that happened in the last n seconds in the LHS?

Comment: Use a time stamp that is a fact attribute. -- Certainly, the "fact" Now needs to be updated - time is always on the move.

Comment: Yes, you can use a time window to locate events within certain intervals. Your Q didn't sound as if this was your problem.

Comment: Syntactically, how can I retrieve the latest `Event(some_constraints)` from a time window in a rule's LHS?

Comment: Also, if I want to use a fact with an explicit timestamp field, what is the correct way of setting that field up to match Drools' real time clock? (i.e. `long time = System.currentTimeMillis()?)`

Comment: Use java.util.Date for a timestamp. - The latest event of a kind is one where there is `not Event(this after $other)`.